# Javascript: Window event, document event or element event?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

- Dispatch a window event:
- Dispatch a document event:
- Dispatch an event from an element:

All of these methods achieve the same result in this sample below, so what reasons are there for preferring one over the others?
This is a (somewhat simplified) representation of a choice I need to make for my project.

```js
function addWindowEvent(name,fromElem) {
        const event = new CustomEvent(name, { detail: fromElem.id});
        window.dispatchEvent(event);
}
function addDocumentEvent(name,fromElem) {
        const event = new CustomEvent(name, { detail: fromElem.id});
        document.dispatchEvent(event);
}
function addElementEvent(name,fromElem) {
        const event = new CustomEvent(name, { detail: fromElem.id});
        fromElem.dispatchEvent(event);
}
function showResult(e,n) {
        document.getElementById("div"+n).innerText = 'Event sent from: ' + e.detail;
}
window.addEventListener('myEvent', event => showResult(event,1));
document.addEventListener('myEvent', event => showResult(event,2));
document.getElementById('div3').addEventListener('myEvent', event => showResult(event,3));
```

```html
<button onclick="addWindowEvent('myEvent',div1)">
  Send a window event from the element underneath me
</button>
<div id=div1>No event yet</div>

<button  onclick="addDocumentEvent('myEvent',div2)">
  Send a document event from the element underneath me
</button>
<div id=div2>No event yet</div>

<button  onclick="addElementEvent('myEvent',div3)">
    Send an element event from the element underneath me
</button>
<div id=div3>No event yet</div>
```

Comment: Simply put, you may want different actions performed depending on what object triggers the event.

Answer (score 0):

In short You can choose what your prefer. Triggering event on element and on document is little less performant because of event capturing phase.

Comment: Thanks, can you be a little clearer on which may be more efficient with performance?